# Using two diferent searchs per language

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a script that sends my invoices by Batch.
And now I add another subsidiary that speaks in Portuguese.

After the script runs it shows a specific search, and now I want to add another, if the subsidiary is the Portuguese one this search will run.

How Can I do that?

This is how this part of my script is today:

var mySearch = search.load({ id: 'customsearch_rsmbr_cust_email_sent' })
redirect.toSavedSearchResult({ id: mySearch.id })

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is what you're looking for.

```
//get subsidiary from current user
var user = runtime.getCurrentUser();
var subsidiary = user.subsidiary;
//or get subsidiary from current record
var recId = XXX;
var curRec = record.load({id: recId, type: record.Type.INVOICE});
var subsidiary = curRec.getValue({fieldId:'subsidiary'}); //returns the record's subsidiary

var searchId ;

//set searchId based on subsidiary
if(subsidiary == 1){
    searchId ='customsearch_searchId1';
} else if (subsidiary == 2){
    searchId ='customsearch_searchId2';
}
//load search
var mySearch = search.load({ id: searchId });
//redirect user
redirect.toSavedSearchResult({ id: mySearch.id });
```